# Issue connecting to mysql

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm trying to run a simple Python code on IDLE on Mac (Python3) , but

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/Users/.../Documents/connDB.py", line 1, in 
> import mysql.connector
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

```
(base) lib % which mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql

(base)  lib % which python
/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/python

lib % which python3
/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/python3

 mysql -u root -p         
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 25
Server version: 8.0.32 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

So what is stopping Python to be able to connect to my db?

Answer (score -1):

Alright.. I think the issue is either you haven't installed the mysql-connector library or you're not in the correct python environment. Since it most likely be the first case, you have to run the following code in your command line.

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Then try running the script.

If it didn't fix your error and you're sure that you installed mysql-connector-python, then you're in the wrong python environment. Since you're using conda first try to view the environment list by running

```
conda env list
```

Then activate the environment by running

```
conda activate environment_name
```

Then you're all done. Try running the script again and it should work fine.

P.S : Can anyone explain the reason why I got downvoted?